# How to move data from one listview to another in C#?

Tags: c#, listview

How to move data from one listview to another using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListViewItem itemClone;
ListView.ListViewItemCollection coll = listView1.Items;
foreach (ListViewItem item in coll)
{
itemClone = item.Clone() as ListViewItem;
listView1.Items.Remove(item);
listView2.Items.Add(itemClone);
}
```

Comment: Moving requires you to remove the item out of the first listview as well. :) (which will not work inside a foreach loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
ListViewItem listItemToMove = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
ListViewItem itemToAdd = (ListViewItem)listItemToMove.Clone ();
listView2.Items.Add (itemToAdd);
listView1.Items.Remove(listItemToMove);
```